# Using jar file with phonegap/cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, maven, gradle, phonegap-plugins

I'm doing a plugin for cordova v5.0.0
the plugin works fine with gradle dependencies, but I need to use a jar file

so I added the file to the source-code section at plugin.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="SygicPlugin">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.test.plugi"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/android/libs/MyJar.jar" target-dir="src/libs/" />        
    <source-file src="src/android/MyPlugin.java" target-dir="src/" />
    <framework src="src/android/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
 </platform>
```

And this is my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

but the android build process is failing:

> MyPlugin.java:4: error: package com.test.jars.model does not exist
>   import com.jar.jarType;

I have found a lot of "examples" using ant for building, but I'm using gradle and I want to continue using it.

Do you know how to use a jar from a plugin and configure the gradle for build correctly?

Thanks in advance.

W

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was that it was not finding the jar file, but it fails silently.
When I change the file to:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile name: 'MyJar'
}
```

I can see the error. The path libs does not exist.
So I needed to use the same path used in my plugin.xml file src/lib to my jars. It's so obvious... I feel like a noob :)

My final build.gradle file is:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'src/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```